# How can I write text to a specific location of a line in another file?

Tags: java

I need to read these values from a text file

4100203
2142430
2403039

and write them (individually) to a specific point in another text file.

Example:

Read '4100203' from input file and Write it to a line in the destination text file that says '  '

Desired output:

[value] 4100203 [value]

After this has completed, I need the process to be repeated such that output is:

[value] 2142430 [value]

but saved as a new output file, and so forth with the rest of my values inside of my input file.

If you can help that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to open a temporary file with the current contents of the destination file, modify that, then write it to the file through a `FileWriter` or similar.